# Trying to get into a member function through main... not so sure how to do so

Tags: c++, list, function, member

The two header files are :

```
    #ifndef VIDEO_H
#define VIDEO_H

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Video
{
public:
    Video(string title, string URL, string comment, float length, int rating);
    ~Video();
    void print();
    bool longer(Video *Other);
    bool higher(Video *Other);
    bool alphabet(Video *Other);
private:
    string m_title;
    string m_url;
    string m_comment;
    float m_length;
    int m_rating;
};




    #endif
```

And the second one....

```
#ifndef VLIST_H
#define VLIST_H

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Vlist
{
public:
    Vlist();
    ~Vlist();
    void insert(string title, string URL, string comment, float length, int rating);
    bool remove();

private:
    class Node
    {
    public:
        Node(class Video *Video, Node *next)
        {m_video = Video; m_next = next;}
        Video *m_video;
        Node *m_next;
    };
    Node* m_head;
};


#endif
```

I am trying to access a member function called insert, but im not so sure on how to do so.... this is what i had came up with so far.

```
  Array[i] = new Video(title, URL, comment, length, rating);
            Vlist *list = new Vlist;
            list->insert(title, URL, comment, length, rating);
```

there is more code above and below it, but this is the area that I am having the problems on.  It would read that on the line (Vlist *list = new Vlist;) : undefined reference to 'Vlist::Vlist()'

Comment: You have declared but not defined your `Vlist` constructor. Give it a body

Comment: I did in a file called vlist.cpp i just forgot to put that one up too.

Comment: Post it here. Also check your linkage settings and make sure you **link** all your compiled objects

Answer (score -1):

Did you #include"video.h" and #include "vlist.h" within main?  It appears you have created an object of Vlist and accessed the objects member properly.  How is main defined?  What do you think is the reason you are unable to access a public member with an object of the class?

One suggestion is that you avoid using declarations in header files and prefix with std::

Comment: at the very top of main there was a #include "video.h" and #include "vlist.h"

Comment: Way you are accessing the member function appears correct providedyou have compiled your code correctly.  What you provided looks correct to me.